# Prove the convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( (n+1)^\frac1n-(n)^\frac1n\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$u_n:=(n+1)^\frac{1}{n}-(n)^\frac1n$$
How to prove the convergence  or divergence of the series $\sum u_n$ ?
I tried the usual criteria but failed.

Comment: What is the partial sum?

Comment: @CYKwong Did you misread this as a telescoping series?

Comment: yes. my mistake

Comment: this series converges

Answer (score 9):

With $f(x)=x^{1/n}$, we have $(n+1)^{1/n}-n^{1/n}=f'(\nu)$ for some $\nu\in(n,n+1)$ (Mean Value Theorem).
With $f'(x)=\frac{x^{1/n}}{nx}$, this makes
$$0<u_n<\frac{(n+1)^{1/n}}{n^2}. $$
The numerator tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty$. In fact from $n+1\le2^n$ for $n\ge1$, we find $$0<u_n<\frac2{n^2}$$ so that $\sum u_n$ converges by comparison with a well-known converging series.

Answer (score 5):

we have the next inequality is true for $n \geq 6$:
$$(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}-n^\frac{1}{n}<(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}-(n+2)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$
this is a telecopic sum, therefore:
$$\sum_{n=6}^\infty u_n<\sum_{n=6}^\infty\left((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}-(n+2)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)=(6+1)^\frac{1}{6}-\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+2)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}=7^\frac{1}{6}-1$$
In the case when $n=0$ we have $u_0=e$

therefore $u_n$ converges

God bless us

Comment: this is perhaps the nicest answer

Comment: the answer seems fine but it is not clear that $n^{1/n}>(n+2)^{1/(n+1)}$

Comment: Indeed, @Masacroso  $3^{1/3}<5^{1/4}.$ So this answer is problematic.

Comment: The graph below indicates the sum is more than $1$...

Comment: It is true for large $n$, however, that $n>(1+2/n)^{n}$ since the right hand side converges to $e^2$ and is thus bounded. This means that $n^{n+1}>(n+2)^n$ and you get your inequality for large enough $n$.

Comment: Guys I fix the problem, thanks for yours suggestions

Answer (score 4):

$$
u_{n} = {(n+1)}^{\frac{1}{n}}-{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
u_{n} = e^{\frac{ln(n+1)}{n}}-e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}\\
u_{n} = e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}(e^{\frac{ln(n+1)-ln(n)}{n}}-1)\\
u_{n} = e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}(e^{\frac{ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n}}-1)\\
u_{n} \sim  e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}(e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}-1)\\
u_{n} \sim  e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}.\frac{1}{n^2}\\
u_{n} \sim  \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
The last line comes from the fact that

$$
e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}} \sim 1
$$
We conclude, then, that the series converge

Comment: Your third line is incorrect. It should be $$u_n=e^{\ln(n)/n}$$ times your right side.

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll correct that, thanks^^

Comment: can you please explain the fourth to fifth line

Comment: using l'hopitals rule, you should get $e^{-1/(n(n+1))}$

Comment: @gebra $\frac{ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n} \sim \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: approximately $-1/n^2$ is more like it right?

Comment: @gebra You can quickly check that it's not the right answer since $ln(1+\frac{1}{n})>0$ but $-\frac{1}{n^2}<0$

Comment: Well you should handle this problem with some caution. Since $\log(1+1/n)/n\sim 1/n^{2}$ you can't automatically conclude that $e^{\log n/n} (e^{\log(1+1/n)/n}-1)\sim e^{\log n/n} (e^{1/n^{2}}-1)$. After all $\sim$ is not the same thing as $=$. It is best to use the fact that $\log n/n\to 0$ and $n\log(1+1/n)\to 1$ and show that $n^{2}\{(n+1)^{1/n}-n^{1/n}\}\to 1$ and thus the series converges by comparison with $\sum 1/n^{2}$.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif right, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution (so please don't down-vote it)... but merely a graph of the summed series up to $n = 10,000$:

[image]